# How to delete all lines containing certain words, except those containing certain words?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file called `file1.txt`. I'd like to delete every line containing the words, "center of", "farm", or "middle of", etc. except lines which contain "①" or "city".

- The list of deletions and exceptions is quite long.
- The files are in UTF-8.

How can I delete every line containing at least one of these words, but not those lines which have some of the exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '/center of\|farm\|middle of/{/①\|city/!d}' file1.txt
```

or

```
sed -i '/center of/ba
        /farm/ba
        /middle of/ba
        b 
        :a
        /①/b
        /city/b
        d' file1.txt
```

and if you have a `words.txt`and `exceptions.txt` files, use this:

```
sed '/\*exceptions\*/{h;s/.*/:a/p;d}
    x
    /./{x;s|.*|/&/b|p;$!d;s/.*/d/;q}
    x
    s|.*|/&/ba|' words.txt - <<<"*exceptions*" exceptions.txt > file.sed
sed -i -f file.sed file1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r '/①|city/{p;d};/center of|farm|middle of/d' file1.txt
```

Comment: I'm always a bit sceptical about doing the wrong thing first, and then fixing it up afterwards... In this case, duplicating lines and then deleting the original. There's no need for that. You could use `b` (as in potong's answer) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/blacklist/{/whitelist/p;d}' file
```

Delete the blacklist, except it is in the whitelist:

```
echo -e "a b\nb c\nc d\nd e\ne f" | sed '/c\|d/{/a\|b/p;d}'
```

prints

```
a b
b c
e f
```

which is every line, which does not contain c or d, and lines containing c or d only if they contain a or b.

Comment: This will duplicate lines such as "This is a city.".

Comment: @hvd: You're absolutely right! I corrected my script which is now similar, but not the same as kev's solution.